# maven wildfly plugin not working in gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab, wildfly

I am trying to deploy a project to wildfly using the wildlfy-maven-plugin. I am trying to deploy using this command:

```
mvn -f nmedical-admin-api/pom.xml wildfly:deploy
```

If i run this directly in my shell everything works fine, but if i run this inside a gitlab pipeline (.gitlab-ci.yml file) then it does not work; it does not find the plugin

```
No plugin found for prefix 'wildfly' in the current project and in the plugin groups
[org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories 
[local(/home/mono/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
```

Any ideas

Comment: Is the plugin defined in your `pom.xml` or what it installed outside of Maven?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, i had to add this lines in my settings.xml

```
<pluginGroups>
   <pluginGroup>org.wildfly.plugins</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

After that, i worked fine

Comment: That should not be required if you have the plugin defined in your POM.

Comment: i had the plugin defined in the pluginManagement section of my POM but for some reason it was not working,

Comment: It needs to be defined in the plugins section. The `pluginManagement` section is for inheriting plugins/configurations. It doesn't make the plugin available for use. https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management